# Can someone from the United States go to a foreign country with a degree from an unaccredited college and legally use it on their resume?

Tags: united-states

So under the majority of united states law, from what I understand, any corporation can call them selves "University" or "college" and give out degrees (With exception to Medical, Lawyer, ect) But nothing is stopping them for giving out a degree in Egganomics or Physcoanalysis because these aren't legally protected terms. The thinking is that the businesses and organisations can take in to a count the credentials.   But countries like United Kingdom have laws regarding what is considered a "degree". So if I had a degree from "Hudson University" with a degree in say Egg Engineering would the United Kingdom accept the United States decision for it being considered a degree? Or would they call it quackery and arrest me for fraud?

Comment: Welcome back to the site.  I think you should narrow this down to a single foreign country, since every country may have its own laws about this, and you can't really expect someone to research all of them to answer your question.  If it's specifically the UK that interests you, then frame your question to be about the UK specifically (and add the [tag:united-kingdom] tag).  Also, this question doesn't really have anything to do with US law, so the tag [tag:united-states] isn't really applicable.

Comment: I think there is a misconception here: *"accept the United States decision for it being considered a degree"*, the United States does not accredit colleges or degrees, those are done by an accreditation body, which are not affiliated or sponsored by the US Government. Accreditation adds merit to a degree program, but it is not required of them (and there are many colleges offering non-accredited degree programs).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the laws of the particular country, but in most European ones misrepresenting your qualifications is grounds for instant dismissal. It's only a crime if you are performing certain restricted duties such as practising medicine or providing legal services.

In your example you use relatively benign fake degrees. The most likely outcome would be that your deception is discovered through a simple Google search, and if you were somehow offered the job already you would be fired immediately without severance.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how you listed it. A UK employer can't reasonably be expected to know the higher education law and practices everywhere in the rest of the world, so if you put on your CV that you have a degree from "Hudson University" then that might be considered to be claiming that it is a "real degree" from something comparable to a UK university, and hence being deliberately deceptive. On the other hand if you said it was from "Hudson University (non-accredited)" then you have told the truth.

As for consequences, an employer who spots it is going to mark you down for not being honest, or if they don't spot it you might well be sacked if someone figures it out later. I believe that this is theoretically fraud, but if everyone who over-polished their CV was charged with fraud the courts wouldn't have time for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

They would call it quackery - you would not be arrested for fraud provided you did not use it in a way designed to mislead.

Comment: Interesting..So you're saying they'd just dismiss it all together?

Comment: Dale told you the legal consequences - you won't be arrested for fraud. There are other consequences; if an employer relied on your statement believing it was a "real" degree you would likely be fired.